# IQueryable into a hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, dataset, telerik, iqueryable, hierarchical

I currently have an IQueryable of Questions.  In my Question object I have and "id" and a "parentId" which can be used to create a hierarchy.  Currently, I bind a RadTreeView to the IQueryable of Questions and the RadTreeView takes care of creating the hierarchy because I define the dataId and dataParentId for the TreeView in the markup.  I am now in need of actually having the data sorted into a hierarchy PRIOR to passing it off to my RadTreeView.  How can I do this?

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by "sorted into a hierarchy".  Are you wanting to create an actual object graph, or are you still thinking of it as tabular data?

Comment: Just as data.  In my case, a List of Questions in hierarchical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a numeric field to the table, and populate it by recursively walking the tree and filling the numeric field with an incrementing value.

```
ParentID   ID      Sequence
1          7       1
1          4       2
1          9       3
2          6       4
2          5       5
2          3       6
```

..etc.

Comment: That would just bring the parents to the top and the children to the bottom.  I need it actually grouped like a hierarchy in the actual data.

Comment: Still not following.  How are you determining Sequence?

Comment: You need some code that walks the tree in proper order, adding the incrementing number to the table as you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the SQL Server, you can set something up using Common Table Expressions to return data in the proper order.. See:

http://a-kicker-n.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-sort-hierarchical-recursive.html

See also: [Hierarchical data in Linq - options and performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance)