# asp.net MVC database driven navigation menu

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, menu, navigation

can anybody point me in the right direction as to how I would go about implementing a hierarchical navigation menu which is driven by database?  I don't want to re-invent the wheel here, so I was wondering if there is something that's already been done.  I'm aware of the Menu control in asp.net, but from what I figure it won't work with MVC.  Is there something that's already provided as part of the framework that I can leverage for this purpose?  If not, then maybe a few links to point me in the right direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LBushkin's idea is a good one.  For ways to emit the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags from the database, have a look at the following blog posts:

**ASP.NET MVC Recursive TreeView Helper**
http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2009/02/08/asp.net-mvc-recursive-treeview-helper.aspx

**Rendering a TreeView using the ASP.NET MVC Framework**
http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/10/rendering-tree-view-using-mvc-framework.html

I personally use a modified version of Matt Hidinger's recursive TreeView Helper, and feed it a couple of `IQueryable`s from my database.

Comment: Is there any code for reading the data from database and populating the tree with LINQ to SQL or LINQ to ADO.Net entity?

Comment: @Tanmoy: See here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance

Answer (score 2):

You may want to [look at superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#getting-started) - it's a jQuery compatible menu control that's flexible and uses semantic markup. You can menus by just emitting an appropriate set of `<ul>` and `<li>` tags. They can even be nested to create hierarchical menus by just nesting lists within other lists.

It doesn't directly interface with a database representation - but it's easy enough to emit such a structure into markup as `<ul>` tags and apply superfish to it.