# Fetch history of records using LINQ

Tags: linq, entity-framework, history

I am using entity framework with repository pattern and unit of work objects..

I have an entity Request with properties "RequestId", "OldRequestId", which can be accessed using requestRepository object.

eg: requestRepostiory.GetAll(), requestRepository.GetFiltered(r=> r.Requestid =10)

- If I pass a RequestId, it should retrieve me the specific record.
- If the OldRequestId is not null in the retrieved record, it should bring the old request data as well.
- It should go on until the OldRequestId is null.

[image]

Comment: I believe you are going to want to use a recursive CTE for this.  This is not directly supported in EF (as far as I know) but take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929535/writing-recursive-cte-using-entity-framework-fluent-syntax-or-inline-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Simple way would be something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Data> GetRecursive(int id)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var tmp = GetFiltered(x => x.Requestid == id);
        yield return tmp;

        if (tmp.OldRequestId.HasValue)
            id = tmp.OldRequestId.Value;
        else
            yield break;
    }
}
```

Please note, that this code would run make multiple queries towards the database. Performance won't be the best, but it might work for your scenario.