# Get all parents using Entity Framework 6 and LINQ - parent-child relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get all parents for a given `Category` as efficient as possible. I have found some old threads suggesting to use `cte` and `view` in the database but preferably I would like to avoid creating these altogether. Is there anyway I can do this without having to do multiple round trips to the database getting every parent until parent is null? If possible I would like to do it using `LINQ Dot Notation`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11929928/3850405

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Recursive-or-hierarchical-bf43a96e

Model:

```
public class Category 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why make ParentId an integer.  Instead use : public Category Parent;

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed in this area, so the linked posts still apply.

Comment: @IvanStoev Ok thanks for info. I only have three-four levels maximum in my current project so I decided to do it in code anyway. If we can't take the performance hit I will redo it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46227096/3850405