# How to only select child entities of an entity in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to select only child below `CFO` and its subchild entities in an Entity Framework select statement.

Here's my table:

```
+-------+------------+----------+
| OrgId | Name       | ParentId |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 1     | COO        |          |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 2     | CFO        |          |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 3     | Accountant | 2        |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 4     | Bookkeeper | 3        |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 5     | Controller | 2        |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 6     | Operations | 1        |
+-------+------------+----------+
```

I'd like to select only this:

```
+-------+------------+----------+
| OrgId | Name       | ParentId |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 3     | Accountant | 2        |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 4     | Bookkeeper | 3        |
+-------+------------+----------+
| 5     | Controller | 2        |
+-------+------------+----------+
```

**The entity framework select:**

```
public virtual IList<OrgStructureModel> GetAll()
{
    using (var db = _context)
    {
        var result = _session.GetObjectFromJson<IList<OrgStructureModel>>("OrgStructure");

        if (result == null)
        {
            result = db.OrgStructures
                .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentId == org.OrgId).Count() > 0))
                .ToList();

            _session.SetObjectAsJson("OrgStructure", result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved in EF?

**Here's what I've tried**
I've tried testing to just show child with any parent `.Where(e => e.ParentId != null)`:

```
            result = db.OrgStructures
                .Select(org => org.ToOrgStructureModel(db.OrgStructures.Where(s => s.ParentId == org.OrgId).Count() > 0))
                .Where(e => e.ParentId != null)
                .ToList();
```

But this returned 0 results

Definition of `ToOrgStructureModel`:

```
public static OrgStructureModel ToOrgStructureModel(this OrgStructure org, bool hasChildren)
{
    return new OrgStructureModel
    {
        OrgId = org.OrgId,
        ParentId = org.ParentId,
        Name = org.Name
        hasChildren = hasChildren
    };
}
```

**Update:**
It looks like something's wrong with the Telerik TreeList Control where the above query has data, but the control won't output the data. But the question remains, how do I get `OrgId: 3,4,5` with LINQ?

Comment: can use join method of LINQ

Comment: If anyone has an example, it would be great, thanks!

Comment: Is this not where parentid == null then?

Comment: If I choose `OrgId: 2` should I get back `OrgId: 3, 5` or `OrgId: 3, 4, 5`?  The first answer is easy, the second one is impossible because it requires a [Recursive CTE which Entity-Framework does not support (linq nor lambda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929535/writing-recursive-cte-using-entity-framework-fluent-syntax-or-inline-syntax).

Comment: @ErikPhilips should get back `OrgId: 3,4,5`. After your edit:  I see so stored proc it is!

Answer (score -1):

Only bring back the results where the ParentId is not null.

Comment: Edited question to be more clear. (Added another row)