# Iterations and array in T-Sql

Tags: t-sql

Let's say I have this class Location, which represents locations.

```
public class Location
{
  public int LocationID { get; set; }
  public int JuridictionID { get; set; }
  public int LocationName { get; set; }
}
```

**Exemple:** Silver Spring is located in Montgomery County, which is located in Maryland, Which is located in the USA. Thus, **JuriditionID** for Maryland would be the the **LocationID** for the USA, and so on.

```
public List<Location> SetHierarchyOfLocation(int JuridicitionID)
{
        var list = new List<Location>();
        if (JuridicitionID > 0)
        {
            while (JuridicitionID > 0)
            {
                var location = new Location();
                location = GetLocationByID(JuridicitionID);                    
                list.Add(location);
                JuridicitionID = location.JuridictionID;
            }
        }
        list.Reverse();
        return list;
    }

pubilc Location GetLocationByID(int LocationID)
{
  return db.Locations.FirstOrDefault(l => l.LocationID == LocationID);
}
```

This works perfectly. But, now I realize that it will result in a lot of single calls to the database.

But I don't know how to write a **stored procedure** that will replace this. Can someone help me???

Thanks.

Comment: Which SQL Server version?  You may want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202912/hierarchical-data-in-linq-options-and-performance

Comment: You probably want `jurisdiction` - note the **s**. Avoid spelling mistakes in your code. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/30895/should-i-point-out-spelling-grammar-related-mistakes-in-someones-code

Comment: Thanks. but that's not English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a table like yours called [location]

```
create table location(locationid int, JuridicitionID int, placename varchar(30))

insert location values(1, 0, 'USA')
insert location values(2, 1, 'Maryland')
insert location values(3, 2, 'Silver Spring')

go

create procedure SetHierarchyOfLocation(@JuridicitionID int) 
as
begin
;with cte as
(
select placename, JuridicitionID
from location where JuridicitionID = @JuridicitionID
union all
select t.placename, t.JuridicitionID
from cte join location t on cte.JuridicitionID = t.locationid
)
select placename from cte
order by JuridicitionID
end

go
exec SetHierarchyOfLocation 2
go
```

Comment: When I execute the SPROC with 3 as parameter, I get USA, Maryland, and Montgomery County 4 times. It looks like the answer is good, except that I'm getting everything 4 times.

Comment: @Richard77 I think you have some corrupt data

Comment: That's possible. can u add more data yourself so that we can see how the above code behave???

Comment: @Richard77 I see what you mean. It has been fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I found your solution in a new book I just bought. APress, SQL SERVER 2008 TRANSACT-SQL RECIPES, Joseph SACK, p. 59